# Vuejs form submit not working

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I want to submit the values in my form but each time I press the submit button I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: login is not a function
at Object.submit [as fn] (eval at Yr (vue.min.js:7), <anonymous>:2:369)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (vue.min.js:6)
```

In my HTML code I have my form declared as such: `<form v-on:submit.prevent="login">`

In the JS it looks like this:

```
// register
Vue.component("login-form",
{
    template: // THE HTML FORM
,
    data: function () {
        return data;
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.isAuthenticated = this.checkIfAuthenticated();
        this.userName = localStorage.getItem("id_name");
    },

    methods: {
        checkIfAuthenticated: function () {
            const users = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "tom"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "brian"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "sam"
                }
            ];

            this.$set("users", users);
        },
        login: function () {
            const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };

            $.ajax({
                url: "/token",
                type: "post",
                data: `username=${this.login.username}&password=${this.login.password}`,
                headers: headers,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.info(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    this.isValid = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
// create a root instance
var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#loginForm"
});
```

As you see the login function is in my methods, so I don't see why vue is throwing the error

Edit: inluced a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96naygmg/). The problem happens when you submit the form (after you click on login)

Comment: Can you add your templated?

Comment: Yeah sure. this is the entire JS file: http://pastebin.com/5tQgyjYD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your instance has a conflict. There is a `login` property in a component and there is a `login` method in `Vue` instance. Try to use different names. [Issue at vuejs github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/565):

> Both data properties and methods will be set on the instance, so the
>   short answered is: don't use conflicting names :)

Comment: Yep, can't believe I looked over that. Thanks